# Помогите настроить и подключить sortable.js

Tags: jquery, sortable

Здравствуйте, у меня очень простой вопрос: подскажите пожалуйста как правильно настроить и подключить [sortable.js](http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/), используя jQuery.

- Какие файлы необходимо залинковать
- Как правильно использовать (jquery use)

Сделав так как показано в example:

-подключил скрипт <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/sortable/latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>

-html

```
<ul class="sort_cont">
    <li><a href="#m1">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#m2">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#m3">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

-jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var el = $(".sort_cont");
    var sortable = new Sortable(el);
});
```

В итоге не работает. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно не работает, ведь `Sortable` работает с DOM элементом, а не jQuery-коллекцией:

```
<ul id="list" class="sort_cont">
    <li><a href="#m1">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#m2">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#m3">three</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
   Sortable.create(list);
</script>
```

---

Если хотите использовать с jQuery, то:

```
git clone git@github.com:RubaXa/Sortable.git
cd Sortable
npm install
grunt jquery:min
```

В итоге получите файл `jquery.fn.sortable.min.js`, который можно использовать вместе с jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sort_cont").sortable({ /* options */ });
});
```